# Prime constellation , can we find a prime-vector for $s>13$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

$$v=[0,4,6,10,16,18,24,30,34,40,46,58,60,66,76,84,88,90,94,96]$$

is a so-called prime-constellation. Since for every prime $p$, there is at least one $k$, such that $v_j+k\ne 0\mod p$ for all $j=1,2,\cdots 20$. $v$ is what is called an admissible tuple.

> The object is to find an $s>13$, such that $s+v_j$ is prime for $j=1,2,\cdots ,20$.

For $s=13$ , this is the case and I found out that a larger $s$ must satisfy $s\equiv 13\mod 2310$. Nevertheless, it seems hopeless to find another $s$ with the desired property, although it is conjectured that there are infinite many possibilities because the tuple is admissible. How can I further sieve out the possible candidates to find a second solution ?

Comment: I think I've searched up to 35 billion with no hits (using Python).

Comment: I like this question.  How did you get $s \equiv 13 \pmod{2310}$?

Comment: @user1329514 Otherwise one of the numbers would have a prime factor $p\le 11$

Comment: So then $v_j + s$ gives all the prime numbers in the closed interval of integers $[13, 109]$ when $s = 13$, am I correct in that assumption?

Comment: @user1329514 No, my vector has length $20$, but the interval $[13,109]$  contains $24$ primes.

Comment: Okay, but 210 is maybe easier to work with, initially--I can see about "aiming" a prime residue class with, perhaps a primorial number as the modulus--because the constellation that you've provided $v$, is contained as a subset (not a subgroup) by the multiplicative group, i.e. 
 $v+s \subset (\mathbb{Z}/7\#\mathbb{Z}) ^{\times}$ when $s = 13$.

Comment: Why not use the Hardy-Littlewood prime $k$-tuple conjecture to get a lower bound on the minimal value of $s$?

Comment: @Klangen Even if we assume the conjecture to be true, what is the merit of knowing the LOWER bound ?

Comment: @Peter so that we know where to start looking for an appropriate $s$